# INSTALL_FAILED_EAS_POLICY_REJECTED_PERMISSION?

Tags: android, permissions, installation, policy, failed-installation

Everytime i try to launch my APP Im getting this error in the Console

```
[2014-03-09 10:26:47 - GeocachePlacer] ------------------------------
[2014-03-09 10:26:47 - GeocachePlacer] Android Launch!
[2014-03-09 10:26:47 - GeocachePlacer] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-09 10:26:47 - GeocachePlacer] Performing dk.rocologo.geocacheplacer.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-03-09 10:27:16 - GeocachePlacer] Uploading GeocachePlacer.apk onto device 'eb0b0006'
[2014-03-09 10:27:17 - GeocachePlacer] Installing GeocachePlacer.apk...
[2014-03-09 10:27:19 - GeocachePlacer] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_EAS_POLICY_REJECTED_PERMISSION
[2014-03-09 10:27:19 - GeocachePlacer] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-03-09 10:27:19 - GeocachePlacer] Launch canceled!
[2014-03-09 10:36:32 - GeocachePlacer] ------------------------------
```

I dont know what this error means and what to do to resolve it. I have tried Google `"INSTALL_FAILED_EAS_POLICY_REJECTED_PERMISSION"` but I have only found one who had the same problem when we wanted to root his phone.

I don't want that, I'm just trying to install and run my app, to test if it works?

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me in what direction I should look!

Comment: Did you already check `logcat` output as the error message suggests?

Comment: Yes I did. I have searched for "text: reject", "text: install", "text: pemission", "tag: GeocachePlacer" in logcat but didn't find anything. I don't know what else to look for. I can't find "INSTALL_FAILED_EAS_POLICY_REJECTED_PERMISSION" either. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have found a error in LOGCAT which I don't understand. I says: "E/EnterpriseContainerManager(817): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!" May be this is the error?

Answer (score 6):

I have found the solution: I tried to export the APK file and discovered that it was my Corporate Email which was the problem. When I install my Corporate Email (Outlook / Exchange activesync) the phone / tablet get some a security policy from my company which disables "Unknown sources" in the Security settings. "Unknown sources" was greyed out so I could not enable it.

To solve this I removed my corporate email account from the device and the policy and THEN I was able to enable "Unknown Sources" and THEN I could finally install my APP directly from Eclipse or manually export and install the APK file.

This gives me a new problem. Now I can't read corporate email on my phone :-( If I install the policy again, then I cant install APK files on my phone :-(

You might have the same problem if you use KNOX which is standard on new Samsung Galaxy Devices.